# Imported High Res texture but wrong resolution visualization in UV Editing

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I have this weird problem. I made a large image texture 18000x12000 pixel subdivided in 3x2 squares of 6000x6000 pixels each. I want to map each face on a cube, so I have to move the faces in UV Map editor, pretty simple.

However in UV Map editor I see a lower resolution of my image. The pixels are not squared anymore and I see a vertical smudge in the vertical transition of my square faces but I need the thing I see in Photoshop.

In the red box is how I see same thing in Photoshop.

[image: Blender vs Photoshop]

I can save each squares alone but it is a step I would not want to take if possible.

Edit: For anyone who want to test it here a sample file. Just zoon in in UV Editor and confront it with the real texture in Photoshop
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11q7DyFVX4XEim2ZU4AOlbUdY-RkGqmq-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you upload your Blender file and the texture file?

Comment: Sure! Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11q7DyFVX4XEim2ZU4AOlbUdY-RkGqmq-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Indeed something is off, I used pixel snapping to snap to a single pixel and it looked this way: https://i.imgur.com/kMREN09.gif It's not just a display issue in UV Editing mode, as the effect goes to the render. After resizing the image down, the issue would go away. After resizing it back up it would return, which makes me suspect it's a bug (or a known limitation)

Answer (score 3):

This is a technical limitation of how the image editor works and your GPU. The cause is that you GPU cannot draw the texture in a single go. Blender downscales the texture so it fits on you GPU and can be drawn.

The current limitation will be addressed but no effort has been made yet.